# definition of characteristic of an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Consider the following definitions taken from the book *Topics in Algebra* by I. N. Herstein.

> An integral domain $D$ is said to be of characteristic $0$ if the
> relation $ma=0$, where $a\neq 0$ is in $D$, and where $m$ is an
> integer, can hold only if $m=0$.
>
> An integral domain $D$ is said to be finite characteristic if there
> exists a positive integer $m$ such that $ma=0$ for all $a\in D$.

I wish to prove that $D$ is of characteristic zero if and only if it is not of finite characteristic.

Suppose $D$ is of characteristic $0$. Then existence of positive integer $m$ such that $ma=0$ for all $a\in D$ clearly contradicts the required condition of characteristic $0$. (I presume there exists a nonzero element in $D$, although this is not done by Herstein.)

Conversely, suppose $D$ is not of finite characteristic. Then there exists no positive integer $m$ such that $ma=0$ for all $a\in D$. How do I proceed next?

My issue is that given the relation $ma=0$ where $0\ne a\in D$ is some fixed element, it may happen that $m'a=0$ for some positive $m'$, although that $m'$ is not "annihilating" all remaining elements and so is not contradicting the hypothesis. And yet that $m'$ is justifying why the ring is not of characteristic $0$.

One idea I had was to establish equivalent definitions using unity, and prove the result using that but Herstein does not endow his integral domains with unity.

Comment: I think that Herstein's definition of characteristic $0$ is that, if $m \in \mathbb N$ is such that $\forall a \in D, ~a\neq 0 : ma = 0$ then $ m = 0$. In this case, what you want to prove is exactly the content of the definition.

Comment: Yes I think so too. Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: You're welcome ! There is also this topic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776849/error-in-hersteins-topics-in-algebra-zero-ring-has-characteristic-1-which?rq=1 where there is a discussion about the definition of an integral domain with unity.